# Python Structured List Not Returning Values Using Reduce with Lambda

Tags: python, list

I have inherited Python code which I don't fully understand yet. Here is a structured list which needs only values from the `Alternatives` key to be returned by a function. The data is *like*:

```
{
 'Response': 
[
 {
  'SavingsMessage': '', 
  'SavingNotification': 
  [
   {'AuthorizationNumber': '12345' 'Alternatives': []},
   {'AuthorizationNumber': '6666', 'Alternatives': [{'NDC': '99999'} ]
  ]
}
```

Above data is in a  `nested_value`  variable and is passed to a function in such format:

```
 level_two = get_nested_value_IRFAN([nested_value,*schema[key][level_one_key][level_one_key]])
```

while the values of the `*schema[key][level_one_key][level_one_key]]` is:

```
[0, 'Response', 0, 'SavingNotification', 0, 'Alternatives']
```

And here is the function itself:

```
def get_nested_value_IRFAN(path):   
  return functools.reduce(lambda a,b:a[b],path)
```

The function should return only the values of the Alternatives key, per my understanding of the code but nothing is returned by the function--just blank `[]` returns? Or I could use `nested_value` variable in a different way to extract the values of the `Alternative` key. I have tried a few things but nothing has worked so far.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you think it will ever go to the second element I that list? In the path you have `0`. `reduce` is probably the wrong thing to use here

Comment: `get_nested_value_IRFAN()` only gets one value from the specified path. You need a loop to get all of them.

Comment: Note, you haven't really defined any of the variables you are using in the code, which you really should. Why make people guess? It is simple and straightforward to make this totally unambiguous

Comment: Use the key `[0, 'Response', 0, 'SavingNotification']` to get to that level, then you can loop and get `item['Alternatives']`

Comment: I am trying to implement what that programmer left behind.

Comment: @Barmar if can please help me out with the logic for the loop? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because comments are limited in space and formatting, I'm posting an answer.

What you've given us:

```
nested_value = {
 'Response': 
[
 {
  'SavingsMessage': '', 
  'SavingNotification': 
  [
   {'AuthorizationNumber': '12345' 'Alternatives': []},
   {'AuthorizationNumber': '6666', 'Alternatives': [{'NDC': '99999'} ]
  ]
}

path = [0, 'Response', 0, 'SavingNotification', 0, 'Alternatives']

def get_nested_value_IRFAN(path):
    return functools.reduce(lambda a,b:a[b],path)

get_nested_value_IRFAN([nest_value, path])
```

`functools.reduce()` takes a function and a dataset to iterate over. The passed in function stores the result of the previous iteration in `a` and gets the new value to use in `b`. On the first iteration it takes in the first 2 elements of the list (`path` in our case).

So the iterations, while applying the function, look like:

```
a = the nested_value data structure wrapped in [], b = 0
a = the nested_value data structed, b = "Response"
a = nested_value["Response"], b = 0
a = nested_value["Response"][0], b = "SavingNotification"
a = nested_value["Response"][0]["SavingNotification"], b = 0
# below is the last iteration
a = nested_value["Response"][0]["SavingNotification"][0], b = "Alternatives"
# which returns nested_value["Response"][0]["SavingNotification"][0]["Alternatives"]
# which is also []
```

You can create a loop to get the other values with minimal effort like so:

```
dkey = schema[key][level_one_key][level_one_key]
level_two = get_nested_value_IRFAN([nested_value,*dkey[:-2]])
for e in level_two:
    # Okay... so this one should work... but if it doesn't, then you can do...
    print(e[dkey[-1]])
    print(e["Alternatives"]
    # do what you want with e
```

Comment: High. Thank you. So are you going to add the loop? It looks like you started to but that is not there yet?

Comment: Oops I see now. Sorry! Thanks.

Comment: You're good... I think I threw an error. I just updated it.

Comment: Hi, I think we are closer but I get the values of key like AuthorizationNumber while I only need for Alternatives key?

Comment: BTW, my print is like: print(level_two) because your print is giving error like unhassable?

Comment: print for your answer gives: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Yah, I wasn't reading the list right... Either one of those print statements should work.

Comment: But your Answer does not have the updated definition of the get_nested_value_IRFAN function? In your Answer, there are two arguments in the function call? Thank you.

Comment: `get_nested_value_IRFAN(path)` is defined in my answer the same as it is in your post. See the beginning of my answer that explains how that function works.

Answer (score 1):

The approach using `reduce` is fine, but there are a few problems with your code and/or data:

- first, your `nested_value` is not structured properly; there are a few closing parens and a comma missing (and possibly and entire outer layer)
- instead of chaining the actual data to the path, you can use the third parameter of [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce): `initializer`
- the first key in your path is `0`, but in your `nested_value`, the outermost structure is a dictionary

Or should there be another list around that? If there is another list, then `[]` would actually be the correct response for the given path and data. In any case, I would suggest at least using the `initializer` parameter to make the code a lot clearer:

```
nested_value = [{'Response': [{'SavingsMessage': '',
    'SavingNotification': [{'AuthorizationNumber': '12345',
      'Alternatives': []},
     {'AuthorizationNumber': '6666', 'Alternatives': [{'NDC': '99999'}]}]}]}]

def get_nested_value_IRFAN(path, data): 
    return functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a[b], path, data)

# using 1 instead of 0 as last list index for clearer output
path = [0, 'Response', 0, 'SavingNotification', 1, 'Alternatives']

val = get_nested_value_IRFAN(path, nested_value)
# [{'NDC': '99999'}], or [] for original path
```

Comment: Thank you. You had an extra ] at the end of the nested_value variable. Anyway, after removing that I ran the code just like your Answer above with hard-coded values but get Keyerror 0.

Comment: Oh, the extra ] was because was missing the initial [. Anyway, I do now see the NDC values returned; let me confirm something but look like almost there! Thanks!

Comment: @IrfanClemson Note that I change a `0` in the path to `1` to get a more "expressive" result and not just `[]`, but for the original path, `[]` would actually be correct.

Comment: Thank you. If I were to make to 0 then still nothing returns. But if 1 then all values are NDC 999 in a loop; I think the [] should also return for downstream check when the Alternatives key doesn't have any value.

Comment: Actually, the same NDC values are returned even though other values exist in the nested_value variable. Hmm.

Comment: @IrfanClemson Maybe I did not entirely understand what you are looking for Do you want _all_ values for the last string-type key in the path across all elements in the different levels of lists? Maybe you should add an example output to your question.

Comment: Hi, it is very confusing me to too! The prev programmer left a big file and what you see is just a small code fragment and I had to comment out a lot of code just to get to the stage to discuss with you. I **think** all values of Alternatives are to be returned. If they are empty then downstreaming process doesn't happen. But they have values then processing is done. **Also, I just tried the @Shmack Answer and looking good there. I hope I had wasted your time! But so much appreciated!!